# Multiselect query returns fewer rows than expected

Tags: mysql, union, union-all

I am trying to select the 5 'newest' rows (The ones with the highest id) and then 10 random rows which should not be any of the 5 newest.

```
(SELECT t1.img_app_id 
 FROM imgs_app t1 
 ORDER BY t1.img_app_id DESC 
 LIMIT 5)
UNION
(SELECT t2.img_app_id 
 FROM imgs_app t2 
 ORDER BY RAND() DESC 
 LIMIT 10 OFFSET 5)
```

But for some reason the last querie does only return 7 rows? the database currently has 29 rows in total.

When i order DESC i should get the highest ids first, and when i use offset 5 i should not get any of the 5 newest rows right?

What am i doing wrong in this SQL?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `ORDER BY RAND() DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 5` is equivalent to `ORDER BY RAND() DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0`, which is nothing else as "5 random rows". You can as well just write `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10`.

So for your second part you would either need to "remove" the first 5 rows in another subquery before you "shuffle" the rows:

```
SELECT img_app_id 
FROM (
    SELECT img_app_id 
    FROM imgs_app
    ORDER BY img_app_id DESC 
    LIMIT 9999999999 OFFSET 5
) sub
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 10
```

Another way (and probably faster) is to use a subquery in the WHERE clause to "remove" the first 5 rows:

```
SELECT img_app_id 
FROM imgs_app
WHERE img_app_id <= (
    SELECT img_app_id
    FROM imgs_app
    ORDER BY img_app_id DESC
    LIMIT 1 OFFSET 5
)
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 10
```

Now you can use `UNION [DISTINCT]` or `UNION ALL`. The result will be the same since there can't be any duplicate. But `UNION ALL` will avoid unnecessary sorting.

The final query would be:

```
(
    SELECT t1.img_app_id 
    FROM imgs_app t1 
    ORDER BY t1.img_app_id DESC 
    LIMIT 5
) UNION ALL (
    SELECT img_app_id 
    FROM imgs_app
    WHERE img_app_id <= (
        SELECT img_app_id
        FROM imgs_app
        ORDER BY img_app_id DESC
        LIMIT 1 OFFSET 5
    )
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 10
)
```

Note that `UNION ALL` allone is not a solution. You will just get some random duplicates.

Comment: I am impressed, i have no idea on what you just did, but it works, i will dive deeper into this querie! thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

`UNION` does the setwise union of the two `SELECT` operations in your query.  If your latest-five query returns some of the same `id` values as your random query, `UNION` suppresses the duplicates.

Try `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason the last offset does not offest from the DESC results